# python lambda PyCharm suggests adding @Property decorator to function

Tags: python, lambda, properties

```
    def establishedSessions(self):
        return reduce(lambda x, y: x and y, loggedInUsers.values())
```

So I have a dictionary of sessions with key of username and value is a Boolean indicating if that user is logged in. I want to know if all users are connected which this function does nicely. PyCharm is suggesting I add a @Property decorator.

I think I kind of understand what the @Property decorator does but I don't see why it would apply in this case.

Comment: This isn't your question, but `all(loggedInUsers.values())` would be a little more concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@property` decorator (not `@Property`) creates a descriptor that allows you to access what looks like a member variable of an object but whose value is the return value of your function. I.e. you would reference `obj.established_sessions` rather than `obj.established_sessions()`.

A property cannot take parameters, and generally should not have side effects. Your function meets both criteria, so it could easily be a property. It doesn't have to be one.